# Proof of Pinsker's inequality.

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, inequality, information-theory

How to prove the following known (Pinsker's) inequality?

For two strictly positive sequences $(p_i)^n_{i=l}$ and $(q_i)^n_{i=l}$   with  $\sum_{i=1}^np_i=\sum_{i=1}^nq_i=1$ one has $$\sum_{i=1}^np_i\log\frac{p_i}{q_i}\ge \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|p_i-q_i|\right)^2.$$

Comment: Retagged due to the relation to [Kullback-Leibler_divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: If it is known, does it have a name? Where did you find it and was a reference to a proof missing?

Comment: @Aryabhata yes it is known. Pinsker's inequality: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42667/two-reference-requests-pinskers-inequality-and-pontryagin-duality

Comment: @Kolmo: Please add an answer. Also, my point was OP knows it is known, and if OP knew the name, they could have done some research before posting it here.

Comment: Check also Beck & Teboulle 2003, "Mirror descent and nonlinear projected subgradient methods for convex optimization", Proposition 5.1 for elementary proof of a weaker inequality with symmetrized KL-divergence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See here. Pinsker's inequality

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42667/two-reference-requests-pinskers-inequality-and-pontryagin-duality

Comment: Is there a simpler proof?

Comment: I find a simpler one from Borwein\& Levis, 2005, page 63.

Comment: @Kolmo can you please point out the condition for equality in Pinsker's inequality?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at Tsybakov 2009 Introduction to Nonparametric Estimation, p.88, also available in the net. Good and simple proof.