# Proving Pinsker's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms, taylor-expansion

I wanna show that for $a$ and $b >0$ and $<1$. Then 
$$2(a-b)^2\leq (a) \log (a) + (1-a)\log(1-a) -(a)\log(b)-(1-a)\log(1-b).$$
If I wanna go from left to right, then I think I gotta use Taylor's but I don't know how. Also, the right hand side I figured out is equal to 
$$(a)\log\frac ab+(1-a)\log\frac{1-a}{1-b}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned, this is a special case of Pinsker's inequality.
The following proof for this special case is taken from [Pinsker’s inequality and its applications to lower bounds](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~madhurt/courses/infotheory2014/l5.pdf):

For fixed $a \in (0, 1)$ define $f:(0, 1) \to \Bbb R$ as
$$
 f(b) = a\log\frac ab+(1-a)\log\frac{1-a}{1-b} - 2(a-b)^2 \, .
$$
Then 
$$
 f'(b) = -\frac ab + \frac{1-a}{1-b} + 4(a-b) = (b-a) \left(\frac{1}{b(1-b)} - 4\right) \, .
$$
The second factor is $\ge 0$, with equality only at a single point ($b= \frac 12$), so that $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(0, a]$ and 
strictly increasing on $[a, 1)$. It follows that
$$
 f(b) \ge f(a) = 0 \, ,
$$
which is the desired inequality. Equality holds only if and only if $b=a$.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to prove [Pinsker's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinsker%27s_inequality). Since both $a$ and $b$ are between 0 and 1, we can think of $(a,1-a)$ and $(b,1-b)$ as binary probability distributions. Let me call them $P$ and $Q$ respectively, so that $P(0)=a$, $P(1)=1-a$, $Q(0)=b$ and $Q(1)=1-b$.

Now it is easy to see that your left hand side is $2\delta(P,Q)^2$, where $\delta$ is the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) between $P$ and $Q$, while the right hand side is the relative entropy, or [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence), $D(P||Q)$.

You can find the proof of Pinsker's inequality in many places, for example here: [Proof of Pinsker's inequality.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127969/proof-of-pinskers-inequality)